# Script to slice csv based on a column and send email to the respective mail addresses using powershell script

Tags: excel, powershell, csv, email, automation

I have a huge csv file with multiple columns, I would like to use PowerShell to slice the csv into multiple csv files based on name of the column name ID and send to the respective email address corresponding to that ID. The email should contain a subject and body.
A sample csv looks like this:
[image: Fields]

Till now I could come up below query in PowerShell:

```
$CSV = Import-Csv -Path .\filename.csv -Delimiter ';'
$some = $CSV | Group-Object -Property ID

foreach ($i in $some) {
    $i.Group |
    Export-Csv -Delimiter ';'-Encoding UTF8 -NoTypeInformation -Force -Path ('C:\TEMP\' + $i.Name + '.csv') 

    if (Test-Path "C:\TEMP\$($i.Name).csv") {

        $SendMailMessageProps = @{
            SmtpServer  = 'servername'
            Port        = 25
            From        = 'xyz@gmail.com'
            Body        = 'Sliced CSV file'
            Subject     = 'File attached'
            To          = $i.Group.Email | Select-Object -First 1
            Attachments = .\$i.Name.csv
        }
        Send-MailMessage @SendMailMessageProps
    }
}
```

Now the script does slice the csv based on the ID column and saves it as for example, 111.csv, 112.csv etc. in C drive Temp folder. I would like to make it work so that it saves the mail information as well and sends the mail to the corresponding email addresses for example, abc1@gmail.com,abc2@gmail.com etc.

Please help with resolving the script so it does that tasks explained above.

Comment: What if the input CSV would contain several email addresses with same ID value? Should the script send the data to all the addresses or not? And, you should first parse the CSV in question to get target email address, and only then call `send-mailmessage`.

Comment: Hi thanks for the comment, the csv contains uniform data, all ids and email addresses are in sync. Sure the call send-mailmessage can be put later too.